# Make each user have it's own UserTransaction

Tags: java, database, wildfly

We have a war that runs on a wildfly server and connects to the database (single service and a single database). The objects that are used to manage connections are provided by WildFly as such:

```
@Resource
private UserTransaction utx;

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

*Above code is from a web service class*

However from what I understand both `utx` and `em` each are the same for each client connecting to the server. This proves to cause problems as there can be transactions that can cancel each other - for example if the first one would call `utc.rollback()` - whatever was happening in the other one would be canceled as well.

The question is - what to do to make WildFly provide unique objects for `utx` and `em`? Alternatively how to  can those objects be made without knowing details about db connection?

Comment: Why do you think `utx` and `em` are shared between clients? It should not be the case, typically they are per request.

Comment: @Guillaume by per request you mean each connection established or that each request by a single client gets it's own `utx` and `em`?

As for why I think that - it's what I've been told by my peers working much longer then me on the project in which it's from. I however don't have enough inside to know one way or the other

Comment: The typical scope is the request: every time a request comes in a new UserTransaction and EntityManager are created and they are cleaned up after the request is completed. It would be very unusual to do it differently, maybe posting the class-level annotations here would clarify what you are doing

Comment: Class is not annotated in any additional way. Nor are classes that inherit that class

Comment: You need to find out how utx and em are assigned in that class, typically they would be injected but they might be set from a constructor or a setter